# Create a single-column from a pandas data frame with n columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a data frame with 3 **columns**: A, B and C as below:

A:
1
2
3

B:
10
20
30

C:
100
200
300

I need to save the values only in a csv file in "one" **row** like this ( no need to save the column  name)

1   2   3   10  20  30  100 200 300

I tried to create a new data frame with only one coumn using pandas, and transpose it, then write it to a csv file.  But I couln't figure out how. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), [`to_frame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and [`T`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html):

```
(df.unstack().to_frame().T
   .to_csv('out.csv', header=None, index=None, sep=' ')
)
```

Or, with help of [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy)'s [`ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html):

```
(pd.DataFrame([df.to_numpy().ravel('F')])
   .to_csv('out.csv', header=None, index=None, sep=' ')
)
```

Output file:

```
1 2 3 10 20 30 100 200 300
```

Comment: thank you! It writes all values in one row AND one column ( only one cell in Excel], they must be written in separate columns. Any suggestion for this part, please?

Comment: I guess this wouldn't be an issue since the values are separated by space. So all good! Big help

Comment: @Ashi you can change the delimiter to comma, tab or use `to_excel` ;)